# HTML5/CSS - Centering a Section within a Div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center my sections within the 'content' div but can't seem to find a way to do so.
I also like to know why the 'content' div has no height even though there are elements within them.
Basically I want the three column section boxes to be in the center.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/VE72c/

```
    body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
    background-color:Silver;
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px; 
    padding-bottom:20px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#content {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#664E44;
    background-color:red;
}

section {
    color:#24292E;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#A8B1B1;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: `overflow: auto` will fix your height problem

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/khE2S/?

Comment: Alternate if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/VE72c/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` on the sections so that they expand the parents height (`#content`) an use `text-align:center;` to center them horizontaly.

See this 
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/VE72c/6/)**

CSS :

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#container {
    background-color:Silver;
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#content {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#664E44;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;

}
section {
    color:#24292E;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:#A8B1B1;
    padding:4px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these, and remove `float: left` from your section CSS.

```
#content {
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VE72c/7/)